# Buttons in graphics

Tags: graphics, button, drawing

I've created a workflow using Drawing Tools. It consists of Images, lines, and in some places I have cut and pasted Button objects. These buttons work fine if you paste directly into the Graphic frame.  However, when you resize the Graphic frame the buttons are not moved, or translated like the primitives (Rectangle[], etc.)

So, I tried pasting the button inside a 'Text' object obtained by clicking on the Drawing Tools palette, it looks ok, however, it is no longer clickable. I then try and paste the button into a 'Mathematical Text' object (the sigma on Drawing Tools), and bingo it's clickable - unfortunately the button image is messed up. Is there a solution?

Comment: Have a look at [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html).

Comment: @Edmund, there is no menu item for Inset so I presume you mean generate the inset button using code. I was looking for a way to cut and paste the button into the graphic.